# References on Rogers-Shephard inequality

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, metric-geometry

> If $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex body containing the origin, let $K'$ be the convex hull of $K$ and $-K$. One of Rogers-Shephard inequalities asserts:
>
> $$\operatorname{vol}(K') \le 2^n \operatorname{vol}(K).$$

This was proven in the following paper: [convex bodies associated with a given convex body.](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-33/3/270)

I'm looking for references, where a different/new proof of the above inequality is presented.

Edit. The motivation for this is the following: there are several analogues or finer version of such inequalities in Euclidean Geometry. I was wondering about a possibility of extending the ideas to a general Riemannian space, such as the Hyperbolic space---the original proof is not  so helpful in creating a generalization. [Here](https://mega.nz/#!axZyFDLD!pHthp8BKlu3ZuWBE8bPZRgqjfDOkXcaUznDOPBV1mr4) is an alternate link to the paper.

Comment: I don't know what the inequality really asserts.  You must have made an error somewhere because when $n=1$ and $K$ is a single point, say $K=\{x\}$, then $\text{vol}_1\left(K'\right)=2|x|$ but $\text{vol}_1(K)=0$.

Comment: After a bit of searching, this seems to be the case: $K'$ is probably the *difference body* $$DK:=K-K=\{x-y\,|\,x,y\in K\}\,,$$ where we have $$2^n\,\text{vol}_n(K)\leq \text{vol}_n(DK)\leq \binom{2n}{n}\,\text{vol}_n(K)\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski The inequality I was looking for is Theorem 3 in the paper. The new convex body is essentially the least convex set that is centrally symmetric to a point $a \in K$ (the notation for this body in the paper is $R_a$.)

Comment: The paper is not visible to me.  Can you make it available?

Comment: @Batominovski Sure. [Here](https://mega.nz/#!axZyFDLD!pHthp8BKlu3ZuWBE8bPZRgqjfDOkXcaUznDOPBV1mr4) is the link.

Comment: Your question is very interesting, but unfortunately, after spending a few hours with it, I see no way to deal with it.  But I feel that this problem must have a simpler solution than that presented in the paper.

Comment: @fermesomme, how about this paper in the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2556v1.pdf)?

Comment: @ArnieBebitaDris Thanks! I'll look into it.